# Suppose that $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ and that $K=\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}$.

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Suppose that $X=\mathbb{R}^n$ and that $K=\mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}$. using the definition of the Fenchel conjugate verify that $\iota_{K}^{*}=\iota_{-k}$ where $\iota_{K}$ is the indicator function.

my first question is am I correct in assuming that that $-k=\mathbb{R}_{-}^{n}$ and if so, does this mean the fenchel conjugate of the indicator function takes in positive values and outputs negative values?

Second I am hoping someone can help along with the following proof:

Given that $\iota_{K}(x)=0$ if $x\in k$ and $\iota_{K}(x)=+\infty$ if $x\not\in k$ we have two cases to consider.

case 1, $ \;\;x\not\in k$
\begin{align}
\iota_{K}^{*}(v)&=\sup(\langle x,v\rangle-\iota_{K}(x))\\
&=\sup(\langle x,v\rangle-\infty)\\
&=-\infty
\end{align}
which not not a supremum.

case 2, $ \;\;x\in k$
\begin{align}
\iota_{K}^{*}(v)&=\sup(\langle x,v\rangle-\iota_{K}(x))\\
&=\sup(\langle x,v\rangle-0)\\
&=xv.
\end{align}
We now must consider the cases where $v<0,v=0$ and $v>0$

and this is pretty much as far as I've got. I know that when $v=0$ then $xv=0$. However, I could use some help with the other two, as well as anywhere else I may have gone wrong. Thank you.

Comment: There lots of illegal manipulations in your attempts. For example, in case 1, you manipulate $\infty$ as if it were a regular real number. Aint you afraid of $\infty-\infty$, etc. ? In passing, yes it's true that $-K = \mathbb{R}^n_-$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll just write down the solution and hope that you catch some tricks from the manipulations :)

Define $\mathbb{R}^n_+ := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | x \ge 0\}$ (the nonnegative $n$th orthant), and $\mathbb{R}^n_- := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n | x \le 0\}$ (the nonpositive $n$th orthant). From these definitions, it's clear that $-\mathbb{R}^n_+ = \mathbb{R}^n_-$. Now, your objective is to show that $i_{\mathbb{R}_+^n}^* = i_{-\mathbb{R}_+^n}$.

Indeed, for any $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we have
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
i_{\mathbb{R}_+^n}^*(x) &:= \sup_{z \in \mathbb{R}^n}\langle x, z\rangle - i_{\mathbb{R}_+^n}(z) = \sup_{z \ge 0}\langle x, z\rangle \begin{cases} \ge \sup_{t \ge 0}tx_i = +\infty, &\mbox{ if some }x_i > 0,\\=0, &\mbox{ otherwise}\end{cases}\\
&= \begin{cases}0, &\mbox{ if }x \le 0,\\+\infty, &\mbox{ otherwise}\end{cases}\\
&= i_{\mathbb{R}_-^n}(x) = i_{-\mathbb{R}_+^n}(x).
\end{split}
\end{equation}